# React Native: getting data by clicking the link

Tags: android, react-native

Friendship requests are sent with a link as in Pubg Mobile or Clash Royale. In React Native, users will be able to share a link and when others click on the link, the data in the link will be added to the user's database. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use Firebase Cloud messaging.
First you need to create a [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) account
You can integrate that into your react native project through this link ([RNFirebase cloud messaging](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage)). Once you installed and setted all the environment, follow the guide about [Notifications](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications). That guide teaches you how to handle push notifications sent by firebase. You will be able to set a listener when a message (like a link) is received and when the user press on it, after that in your app you can access to the data that has been sent and manipulate as you want (like adding it to user's database)